# Apparmor profile cannot run whoami

Tags: python, virtualenv, apparmor

I've got a Python application that is running in a virtual environment and I'm trying to build an apparmor profile for it. It's got a wrapper that looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

## This script is for running the 'fact' command on staging/prod, it sudos to
## the 'fact' user before executing /opt/fact-virtual-environment/bin/fact

## It is installed as '/usr/bin/fact'

WHOAMI=$(whoami)
PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/fact
PYTHON_BIN=/opt/fact-virtual-environment/bin/python
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=fact.settings.staging

if [ "${WHOAMI}" != "fact" ];
then
  sudo -u fact $0 $*;
else
  PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH} DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE}  ${PYTHON_BIN} -m fact.managecommand $*;
fi
```

So we always make sure we sudo to the correct user before starting. However, even with sudo and whoami I running at ux (as shown below, and yes I know ux is bad/unsafe), whoami still cannot get the correct user ID.

```
# Last Modified: Tue Jan 20 09:25:09 2015
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/bin/fact {
  #include <abstractions/apache2-common>
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/bash>


  capability setgid,
  capability sys_resource,


  deny /etc/group r,
  deny /etc/passwd r,
  deny /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ r,
  deny /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ r,

  /usr/bin/sudo ux,
  /usr/bin/whoami ux,

  /bin/bash rix,
  /bin/dash rix,
  /bin/uname rix,
  /dev/tty rw,
  /etc/default/locale r,
  /etc/group r,
  /etc/passwd r,
  /etc/environment r,
  /etc/login.defs r,
  /etc/lsb-release r,
  /etc/fact/fact.ini r,
  /etc/python2.7/sitecustomize.py r,
  #/etc/security/pam_env.conf r,
  /lib{,32,64}/** mr,
  /opt/fact-virtual-environment/** mr,
  /opt/fact-virtual-environment/bin/python rix,
  #/proc/*/fd/ r,
  #/proc/*/mounts r,
  #/proc/filesystems r,
  #/proc/loadavg r,
  #/proc/meminfo r,
  #/proc/sys/kernel/ngroups_max r,
  #/run/utmp rk,
  /sbin/ldconfig rix,
  /sbin/ldconfig.real rix,
  /usr/bin/fact rix,
  /usr/lib{,32,64}/** mr,
  /usr/share/fact/ r,
  /usr/share/fact/fact/** r,
  /usr/share/pyshared/** r,

}
```

and the error:

```
fact
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 1010
whoami: cannot find name for user ID 111
fact is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Because it can't determine the user I'm running as, it sudos to fact anyway and then complains because fact can't sudo. What apparmor setting is needed for whoami to run correctly?

Comment: Problem is within /usr/bin/fact.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the problem is?

Comment: /usr/bin/fact: line 13: [: !=: unary operator expected

Comment: Yes I should quote the string so it doesn't give me that error, but that still doesn't fix the fact that whoami doesn't work and gives me the error `whoami: cannot find name for user ID 0`. That's the error that needs fixing. The other is just some missing quotes.

Comment: I've edited out my bash error to make the real problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I switched out the `whoami` command with $USER. This seems to be the only workable solution.